# Prove or disprove : If $a\equiv b$ mod $m$, when $a,b,m\in \mathbb{Z}$ , then $a^3\equiv b^3$ mod $m^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove : If $a\equiv b$ mod $m$, when $a,b,m\in \mathbb{Z}$ , then 
$a^3\equiv b^3$ mod $m^2$

**My attempt**:

since  $a\equiv b$ mod $m$ then $a=b+mk$ for some $k$

Now $a^3=m^3k^3+b^3+3m^2k^2b+3mkb^2$

$a^3-b^3=m^3k^3+3m^2k^2b+3mkb^2$

from here I stuck

Comment: Now take both sides $\mod m^2$ and proceed from there, since on the other side there is $3 m k a^2$ and not $0$ ,this indicates that this is not always true.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform..thank you so much you edited my question very attractive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $\color{Red}{m \notin \{ \pm 1, \pm 3 \}} $ , 
we will construct a 
$\color{Red}{\text{counter-example}}$!

**Remark(I)**: 
Let  $\color{Red}{m \neq \pm 3}$, 
and  $\color{Red}{m \neq \pm 1}$; 
in this case note that $m^2 \color{Red}{\nmid} 3m$.

---

Let $a:=m+1$ and $b:=1$; 
then one can see easily that:

$$a^3-b^3=(m+1)^3-1^3=\color{Blue}{m^3+3m^2}+\color{Red}{3m}.$$

---

Notice that the above $a$ and $b$ are 
$\color{Red}{\text{counter-example}}$.

[ 
**Suppose on contrary** that $a^3-b^3$ is divisible by $m^2$; 
on the otherhadn note that 
$\color{Blue}{\text{the first two terms}}$ are divisible by $m^2$, 
so $\color{Red}{\text{the third term}}$ must divisible by $m^2$, 
which has an obvious contradiction with remark(I). 
]

---

---

---

---

Note that your assertion is $\color{Green}{\text{true}}$ when 
$\color{Green}{m \in \{ \pm 1, \pm 3 \}} $.

**Remark**: 
Let $m \in \{ \pm 1, \pm 3 \} $; 
in this case 
for every $b,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ 
we have: 
$m^2 \color{Green}{\mid} 3mkb^2.$

---

Notice that $a \overset{m}{\equiv} b$ 
implies that there is an integer $k$, 
such that $a=b+mk$, 
as you noted, therefor we have:

$$a^3-b^3=\color{Blue}{m^3k^3}+\color{Blue}{3m^2k^2b}+\color{Green}{3mkb^2} ,$$

$\color{Blue}{\text{the the first two terms}}$ are divisible by $m^2$,

and by the remark(II) 
$\color{Green}{\text{the third term}}$ 
is again divisible by $m^2$, 
so we are done!

Comment: @Famke...thank you so much... i love mathsstack

Comment: @suresh ; Dear suresh, you are wellcome!

Comment: @accursed Please explain why you have taken two separate cases, and also handled them separately. Just took $a:=m+1$ in the former case; while took in the latter case: $a = b +mk.$ I mean that (i) why made two cases based on value set taken by $m$, and (ii) why handled these cases differently, as stated in more detail earlier by me.

Answer (score 4):

$$1\equiv 5\pmod 4$$
but $$5^3\equiv 13\not\equiv 1\pmod{16}.$$

Comment: @Surb....thank you so much